# Is vptr ever located not at start of object?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, rtti, virtual-functions, dynamic-cast

According to MSDN, [__RTDynamicCast() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770587.aspx) is used to implement `dynamic_cast` in Visual C++. One of its parameters is `LONG VfDelta` that is described as "offset of virtual function pointer in object".

AFAIK the `vptr` is always located at start of object, so offset will always be zero. I've looked closely at disassembly of various code snippets using `dynamic_cast` and I've never seen anything but zero being passed in place of this parameter.

Is `vptr` ever located anywhere but the object start? Can this offset be anything but zero?

Comment: Did you find any example when vptr offset it is not zero?

Answer (score 5):

In case of multiple inheritance there are more then one `vptr` and you need the `offset`. Take a look here: http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2007/02/c-objects-part-3-multiple-inheritance.html

Comment: Okay, there will be several vptrs, but each will correspond to a complete (sub)object of a (sub)type. Won't each vptr be stored at start of corresponding (sub)object?

Comment: @sharptooth: I misunderstood your question (thought you meant the vtable offset). Answer to your question is in virtual inheritance. http://hacksoflife.blogspot.com/2007/02/c-objects-part-5-virtual-base-classes.html

Comment: @Andrew: Indeed, virtual inheritance needs pointers (or offsets) to virtual base location, but...  The virtual base object itself looks as any other polymorphic (sub)object and strarts (in memory) with a pointer to the vtable. So virtual inheritance seems irrelevant here.

Comment: Nope. That's what I also meant in my answer. Instances of classes that do not have virtual bases generally have a vtbl pointer at offset 0. But when virtual bases exist many implementations (not sure what Microsoft does) have a pointer to the first virtual base at offset 0. Also some implementations do not put the vtbl pointer at offset 0 in some cases of multiple inheritance (for example if the first base does not have a vtbl).

Comment: @Analog File: I agree the implementation _may_ put vtable at the beginning or _may_ not. I only said that there are no serious reasons to evict the vtable ptr from the first place, although the implementation (of course) may do what it want. Placing vtable at the beginning (or, more generally, always at the same offset which is usually 0 :) has one obvious advantage: at least one upcast for arbitrary derived class is always no op. It's interesting, however, what MS C++ really does...

Comment: @user396672 question for yourself: what if the base class does not have a vtbl (no virtual functions) and the derived class does? Where would **you** put the vtbl pointer in the derived class layout?

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what Microsoft does, but it's not always true that the vtable pointer is located at offset zero. An example of cases where it may not be is for multiple inheritance (especially if virtual base classes are involved).

Edit:

I'll expand this a bit with examples.

If the first base or a class does not have a vtbl, the derived class will not have a vtbl pointer at offset 0 (such inheritance is bad practice, but is permitted by the language).

If there is a virtual base, the derived class will generally have a pointer to the virtual base at offset 0, not a vtbl pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is used when virtual inheritance exits ( think about the diamond inheritance chart ). This offset is the offset of the class itself inside the object.

If B and C derives from A, and D derives from both.

```
   A
 /   \
B     C
 \   /
   D
```

Then B and C could be in either order in D. This is where the offset comes into action. So when you dynamic_cast an object of type A to type B, it might be different depending on wether the instance is of type B or D.

Finally to illustrate, here is possible layout of different class

```
Class B:  Class C:   class D:
 | A |      | A |     | A |
 | B |      | C |     | C |
                      | B |
                      | D |
```

In this case the offset of virtual function table of B can be either in 0 ( B instance case ), or sizeof( A ) + sizeof( C ) ( D instance case )

Comment: Actually if B and C have A as a virtual base, at offset 0 of classes B, C and D there generally is a pointer or a signed offset referring to class A. If A has a vtbl than that vtbl pointer may be the only one in all the classes (and is at offset 0 only for class A). If A does not have a vtbl at all (bad practice, but legal) then B and C may have a vtbl pointer but it will not be at offset 0 and if they do then D will have at least two vtbl pointers, neither at offset 0.